# The formula is not functioning in struct of array

Tags: c

I am trying to make a formula that counts the monthly payment of the loan for each owner. The other parts of the program such as the input process are functioning. Only the formula part is not functioning. It produces incorrect results(only the second loop). As for the first input and the last input it produces 0.00. Do I need to make the monthly payment as array also? I have tried it but it still the same.

This is my struct definition,

```
    struct details
    {
       char name[30];
       char houseType[20];
       float rate;
       float loanAmount;
       int years;
    };
```

This is my formula definition,

```
    for(int x=0;x<3;x++)
    {

      monthlyPayment=((owners[x].loanAmount*owners[x].rate)+owners[x].loanAmount)/(owners[x].years*12);

      printf("\nname: %s",owners[x].name);
      printf("\nmonthly payment: %.2f",monthlyPayment);

    }
```

This is my struct of array definition,

```
    details owners[3];
```

This is the input process,

```
    void getOwnersData(details& owners)
    {
      printf("enter name: ");
      scanf(" %s",&owners.name);


     printf("enter house type: ");
     scanf(" %s",&owners.houseType);


     printf("enter rate: ");
     scanf(" %f",&owners.rate);


    printf("enter loan amount: ");
    scanf(" %f",&owners.loanAmount);


    printf("enter years: ");
    scanf(" %s",&owners.years);

  }
```

This is the output,

```
    enter name: w
    enter house type: w
    enter rate: 2
    enter loan amount: 1234567
    enter years: 2
    enter name: d
    enter house type: d
    enter rate: 3
    enter loan amount: 123456
    enter years: 3
    enter name: g
    enter house type: g
    enter rate: 4
    enter loan amount: 12345
    enter years: 4

    name: w
    monthly payment: 0.00
    name: d
    monthly payment: 806.90
    name: g
    monthly payment: 0.00
    name: w
    house type: w
    Total: 1
```

Comment: How are you setting the owner elements?

Comment: Could you post a more complete version of your code? This cannot be [reproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in its current state.

Comment: Could you please provide the output?

Comment: `monthlyPayment` calculation is not right. [Amortization Calculation Formula and Payment Calculator](https://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/amortization-calculation.html)

Comment: Alright, I will try to fix the formula using your references.

Comment: I have read your articles. But the formula in my codes were provided by my lecturer in the task. I don't think I can change that. Is there something else that I could fix in the formula?

Comment: This code is **not** a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you using C++ rather than C? This: `details& owners` is C++ for a reference, and not valid in C. Your `scanf`s also do not make any sense -- the format `%s` is used for an `int` and you pass in things like `&owners.name` when it should be `owners.name` for strings. Clearly, the code you are running is completely different to what you have posted here, since this code cannot compile in C.

Comment: My advice is to compile your code with some basic compilation flags, such as `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -g` if using `gcc`/`clang`. Consider also, using [`gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to debug your code. Without an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there is not much else that can be done.

Comment: Yes, I am using C++. I am sorry that its my bad to not aware about that. I will try your suggestions then.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Could you point out the core mistake within an answer please? I try to shorten the list of unanswered questions in my favorite tag.

Comment: In arriving at the payment it does not include the exponential on the numerator or denominator as shown in the link in my comment.